# Rundeck H2 Database clean up

Tags: h2, rundeck

Anyone have an easy way to clean up a Rundeck H2 database?  I just got tasked to make Rundeck run faster and it appears its been going on 5 years with no database cleanup and the database is now over 5GB.

Thanks
Greg

Answer (score 0):

A good way to decrease the size of your database is to delete the executions.

But, the default H2 database is only for [testing](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/database/#default-database), and with that amount of data probably your instance get unstable for use, the best way to avoid that is to configure Rundeck against some backend like [MySQL](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/database/mysql.html#using-mysql-as-a-database-backend) or [PostgreSQL](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/database/postgres.html#using-postgres-as-a-database-backend).

You can [export](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/projects/project-archive.html#export-archive) your projects (with all configuration), configure rundeck using some "real database" as backend, and later [import](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/projects/project-archive.html#import-archive) it.

Also, take a look at [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/maintenance/backup.html#backup-and-recovery).